# Custom SMS Receiver Crashes on First Received SMS [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, sms

I written an android application that can receive sms. The app is working. It can receive sms, but every time the app is fresh from install. Everytime I send sms from emulator to the app (without opening it manually) it crashes or force close but if I open it manually it can receive sms without issue

here is my code for if the app receive sms it will do this code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage [] msgs = null;
    String messageReceived = "";
    String senderPhoneNumber = null;
    long senderTimestamp = 0;
    String strTimestamp = null;

    if (bundle != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];   

        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            messageReceived += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            messageReceived += "\n";
        }

        senderPhoneNumber = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress ();
        senderTimestamp = msgs[0].getTimestampMillis() / 1000L;
        strTimestamp = senderTimestamp + "";

        if(MainActivity.active){
            MainActivity.populateView(senderPhoneNumber, messageReceived, strTimestamp);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            MainActivity.populateView(senderPhoneNumber, messageReceived, strTimestamp);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

       }

}
```

Please someone help me with this. I want to receive sms without opening it manually.

**EDIT**
Here is the stack trace

```
03-05 11:47:47.208: E/Trace(1512): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-05 11:47:47.368: D/AndroidRuntime(1512): Shutting down VM
03-05 11:47:47.368: W/dalvikvm(1512): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4e7f288)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.amzngscrum.alpha2.SMSReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2236)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.amzngscrum.alpha2.CustomAdapterr.<init>(CustomAdapterr.java:26)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.amzngscrum.alpha2.MainActivity.populateView(MainActivity.java:134)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.amzngscrum.alpha2.SMSReceiver.onReceive(SMSReceiver.java:45)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
03-05 11:47:47.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):     ... 10 more
```

**EDIT 2**
here is the popuateview in MainActivity.class

```
public static void populateView(String sender, String message, String timestamp) {


    if(sender == null || message == null || timestamp == null){
    } else {
        final DataHolder data = new DataHolder();
        data.setSenderCPNumber(sender);
        data.setSenderMessage(message);
        data.setSenderTimestamp(timestamp);
        customListViewValues.add(data);
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapterr( customListView, customListViewValues);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cnt.setText("On Queue: " + lv.getAdapter().getCount());
    start();
}
```

and full code of CustomAdapterr.class

```
public class CustomAdapterr extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data = null;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
DataHolder tempValues = null;
int i = 0;

public CustomAdapterr(Activity a, ArrayList d) {
     activity = a;
     data = d;
     inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView cp;
    public TextView mess;
    public TextView ts;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.cp = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.cpnumber);
        holder.mess = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.messages);
        holder.ts = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    if(data.size()<=0) {
        //no data here
    }
    else {
        tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (DataHolder) data.get(position);

        holder.cp.setText(tempValues.getSenderCPNumber());
        holder.mess.setText(tempValues.getSenderMessage());
        holder.ts.setText(tempValues.getSenderTimestamp());
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    }
    return vi;
}

private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{

    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position){
         mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
      MainActivity mainClick = (MainActivity) activity;
      mainClick.onItemClick(mPosition);
    }               
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace, place?

Comment: ok sir, i'll restart first my emulator

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré I included the stack trace

Comment: Please add the CustomAdapterr.java line 26

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: It could be because that activity object is null, but I'd like to see that method's code (MainActivity.populateView and CustomAdapter.<init>)

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré my app is receiving sms and list it on list view

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré I updated the post sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is produced in the constructor of the adapter, I don't know what is `customListView` in your activity but it's null and you should consider checking that out, initially to resolve the issue change this:

`adapter = new CustomAdapterr(customListView, customListViewValues);`
for this:

`adapter = new CustomAdapterr(this, customListViewValues);`

In your `populateView` method.

Comment: after changing it to "this" it has error
"cannot use this on static context"

Comment: Ok I see, the thing is that is not a good practice to have static methods in an Activity and its even worse to call them from outside (a service or receiver for example as your case). To communicate with your activity consider using the LocalBroadcastManager. Check this example: https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277. This one is useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager

This is the more Android-like way to go.

Comment: You should remove the static flag from your `populateViews` method and use the LocalBroadcastManager to communicate with your activity.

Comment: ok sir. i'll try it. thankyou

Comment: If the info is helpful for you, please accept the answer and I will update it accordingly :)